# unset array value and key in session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am almost done making a shopping cart, but I am not sure how to remove items from the shopping cart. I am using arrays which are stored inside a session. So I would like to unset selected items in the array (using a check box which I have added).

**products.php**

```
cat<a href ="Adding-to-cart.php?id=2222"> add to cart<a/><br>
dog<a href ="Adding-to-cart?id=1111"> add to cart<a/><br>
bird<a href ="Adding-to-cart?id=5555"> add to cart<a/><br>
```

**Adding to cart**

```
code 
    <?php 
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['animals']))
    {
    $_SESSION['animals'] = array();
    }

$_SESSION['animals']["".$_GET['id'].""] = 1;


?>
```

**cart.php**

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("items",$con);
//////////////////////////////////////////////
session_start();

// create an array
$my_array=array();


// put the array in a session variable
if(!isset($_SESSION['animals']))
    $_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

// move submit code outside of foreach loop
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['aaa']); $i++) {
    $aaa = $_POST['aaa'][$i];
    $key_var = $_POST['ke'][$i];

    // setting the session spesific session array value different for each key  
    $_SESSION['animals'][$key_var] = $aaa;
}

////removing checked item from shopping cart    
if (isset($_POST['brosrs'])) {

/////////////Things that I have tried/////////////
////unset($_SESSION['animals'][$key_var]);///////

//unset($_SESSION['animals'][$to_unset]); 

} 
////removing checked item from shopping cart/////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
?>

<table >
<tr >
<td ><b>ID</b></td>
<td ><b>Name</b></td>       
<td ><b>Price</b></td>
<td ><b>Subtotal</b></td>
<td ><b>Product ID is</b></td>
<td ><b>Quantity</b></td>
</tr>

<form method="post" action="">
<?php
//// declate the total price and start it as 0 coz its before the actual items added to cart
$total_price=0;
$subtotal = 0;
// loop through the session array with foreach
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{   

////////////////////////////DUMPING EVERYTHING FROM DATABASE////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $key_array = array_keys($_SESSION['animals']);

// Get record where $key exists.
$sql = "SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id IN ({$key}) ORDER BY name";
$myData =  mysql_query($sql,$con);

// Loop through each record and see if $key_array is present in $row['id'] db
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
if(in_array($row['id'], $key_array)){
    // display records 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td >".  $row['id']. "</td>";
    echo "<td class='name'>".$row['name']. "</td>";
    echo "<td class='qtyid'>". $row['price']. "</td>";
    echo "<br/>";   
    $quantity_calc = $value;
    $subtotal = $value * $row['price']; 
    $price = $row['price'];

    echo "<td>" . $subtotal . "</td>";  
            }
            $total_price += $subtotal;

}  

////////////////////////////DUMPING EVERYTHING FROM DATABASE////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // and print out the values quantity

   echo " <td> Product ID is " .$key. " Quantity is  </td>";

    // getting the updated value from input box
    ?> 
        <!-- <td ><input type="text" name="aaa[]" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>" size="2" /></td> -->
        <td>  <input id="numberinputsize" type="number"  size="1" name="aaa[]" min="1" max="10" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>" > </td>
        <!-- take a hidden input with value of key -->
        <td ><input type="hidden" name="ke[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><br></td>

        <!------------------------adding a remove item checkbox ------------------------------>
        <!------------------------adding a remove item checkbox ------------------------------>
        <td> <input type ="checkbox" name="brosrs" value = "<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></input> </td>
        <!------------------------adding a remove item checkbox ------------------------------>
        <!------------------------adding a remove item checkbox ------------------------------>
    <?php

 echo "</tr>";

}

?>

<tr>
<td>Total amount $<?php Echo $total_price; ?></td>
<td><a href="products-legit.php">back to shopping</a></td>
<td> <input class="inputbox" type="submit" value="Update value of key" name="submit"/></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<style>
table { 
width:1000px; 
}
</style>
```

THANKS!

**UPDATE!**
Sorry, but to make it clear guys, I have a products page where I add id to array as key which is stored in session. After clicking add to cart the user is redirected to Adding-to-cart.php page where the array in inserted into the session. Then when you go on cart u can see the items.  The problem is >>> when I have 2 items or more in the cart, and remove the first item, the last item in the cart removes instead.

Comment: So where is the problem? Just *unset* the array element with the item, which you don't need anymore.

Comment: Just simply use `unset`. If you want to destroy all sessions checkout these two methods: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: hi jackie in morning your question was deleted that time i have made a demo page to show you how to solve your prob here is your solution  approach you can use it in your way as per need.. see my answer and select it as answer if it helps.. HappyCoding..!!

Comment: I know how to unset. but when I unset one of the items in the cart. Only the last one deletes in the loop...

Comment: the preson who down -voted f#@#@^% first see Jackie even don;'t know unset function use and to alter the session value he has to call ajax that's why i have saw him how to call ajax on button click get value to be unset and go to ajax page and alter the session.. i m here to help..no to get a point..so go and down vote as you can ......

Comment: Thanks for the information :) Ryan Vincent

Answer (score 0):

this is demo how to have an idea you need to change implementation in your way

cart.php

```
<?php 

ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['data']=array('Cat','dog','bird');
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION['data']);exit;
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#remove").on('click',function(){
        var toRemove=$('#toRemove').val();
        $.ajax('goToRemove.php',{
            data:{"toRemove":toRemove}
        });


    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="add" id="frmAdd" method="post" action="add.php?action=add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="toRemove" value="" id="toRemove"/>
<input type="button" name="add" id="remove" value="ADD">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

goToRemove.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION['data']);
$to_delete=array_search($_REQUEST['toRemove'], $_SESSION['data']); 
unset($_SESSION['data'][$to_delete]);
echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort PRANAV, but how do i implement this to my code exactly?

Comment: man i have saw you the way with cost of my -1 reputation now you have to implement same in your code..

Comment: first give an id to button which allow user to remove on that button click 1)get the item name which he/she wants to delete and                         2)call ajax to unset given name from session

Comment: do one thing post here your html code and these two php file

Comment: ok let me try if again question deleted.. contact me on pranav88raval@gmail.com

Comment: Okay, THANKS ALOT! :)

Comment: in anchor you passed test1.php where the code for that file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95797/discussion-between-pranav-and-jakie).

Comment: test11 is meant to be add-to-cart.php

Comment: @Jakie *I gave u + 1 just then* Don't upvote a post to cancel out any downvote! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253383/3933332

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that your cart is a multi-dimensional array since you have not given an example of your data. An easy way to find and remove an item from a cart is to combine [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) with [array_column();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```js
$cart = array(
  array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Awesome sauce'),
  array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Not so awesome sauce'),
  array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Really awesome sauce'),
);

//search $cart array for the value of 2 in the id key of the array and unset it.
unset($cart[array_search(2, array_column($cart, 'id'))]);

print_r($cart);

/* 
OUTPUT:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Awesome sauce ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Really awesome sauce ) )

*/

/*******Indexed array****************/
$cart = array( '2222' => 1 ,'1111' => 1 ,'6666' => 1 ,'5555' => 1 );
unset($cart['2222']);
print_r($cart);

/*
OUTPUT:
Array ( [1111] => 1 [6666] => 1 [5555] => 1 )
*/
```

Comment: I have uploaded the full code, and yes I am using a multi-dim array :). but my prblem is, when using the unset outside the loop, and ticking one box and removing the item, it only removes the last item in the cart and not the selected one

Comment: @Jakie please post a dump of your array i.e. print_r($array); So I can see the format

Comment: Array ( [2222] => 1 [1111] => 1 [6666] => 1 [5555] => 1 )  if i want to remove 222 which is the 1st item in cart, it will remove the last one 555

Comment: Array ( [2222] => 1 [1111] => 1 [6666] => 1 [5555] => 1 ) so thats the saved array for four items in the cart

Comment: Thanks for the update kurt, much appreciated :). But instead of literary writing unset($cart['2222']); i need to replace the 2222 which the id of the item that is checked. I cant write 2222 555 1111 6666 next to each item before removing it. I need a variable that goes to remove each item

Comment: Further more, ($cart['2222']); would only remove 2222. How do i make it so that when ticking the checkbox dedicated for each id removes a specific item?